# Como hago para que un arreglo me muestre en que índice se encuentra el numero que ingresa el usuario

Tags: javascript, array, funciones, vscode

Tengo un problema que no e podido solucionar, es sencillo y pasa que tengo un problema debido a que no puedo hacer que si el usuario dentro de 5 números enteros que tiene permitido ingresar si repite 2 o mas veces un numero a la hora de imprimir debe mostrar el numero y en que índices se encuentran, básicamente si introdujo 3 veces el numero 12 de 5 números enteros que podía ingresar se debe de mostrar en cuales índices esta el numero 12.

El código que tengo ya me funciona solo me falta que reconozca eso que explique ya que si ingreso 3 veces 12 solo me muestra 1 solo índice de los 3 en lo que se encuentra.

Codigo

```js
numeros = []

function verificacion (veri) {

  veri = prompt ("Introduzca un numero para verificar, Cancelar para salir")

  while (veri != null) {

       if (numeros.find(elemento => elemento == veri) ) {
              alert ("El Numero " + numeros.find(elemento => elemento == veri) + 
              " se ubica en el indice " + numeros.indexOf(veri))
          }else
              alert ("El numero no se encuentra en el arreglo")

      veri = prompt ("Introduzca un numero para verificar, Letra A para salir")
      }
      return "Comprobación Finalizada"    
}

for (i=0; i < 5; i++) {    
   parseInt (numeros [i] = prompt ("Introduzca numeros enteros"))
}


alert (verificacion())
```

Answer (score 1):

El método `indexOf`acepta un segundo parámetro que indica el índice en el que debe empezar la búsqueda. Puedes repetir la búsqueda hasta que `indexOf` devuelva `-1` (no hay más):

```js
const testArray = [0,1,2,3,4,5,4,3,2,1,0,1,2,3]

function buscaIndices(array, valor) {
  const indices = [];
  let index = -1;
  do {
    index = array.indexOf(valor, index + 1); //se busca desde index + 1 (inclusive)
    if (index === -1) { //no hay más repeticiones de "valor"
      return indices; //salimos de la bucle y de la función
    }
    indices.push(index);
  } while (true); //el retrun se encarga de parar el bucle
}

console.log(buscaIndices(testArray, 3));
```

Comment: Gracias!, había observado que acumulando el resultado en una matriz vacía lograba mostrar los índices solo que no lo había estructurado correctamente. 

Gracias por ayudarme :)

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacer un `filter` de los números y en vez de retornar el número, retornar el índice ya luego solo tienes que hacer un `array.join()`

Quedaría algo así:

```
    while(veri !== null){
    const repetidos = numeros.filter((num, index) => {
        if (num === veri) return index;
    })

    if(repetidos.length > 1){
        alert("el Número " + veri + " se ubica el/los indices(s) " + repetidos.join(", "));
    }
    else alert("El número no se encuentra en el arreglo");

    veri = prompt(("Introduzca un número para verificar, Letra A para salir")); 
    
}
```